# Calculator form alternative

Tags: javascript

I have the current code below, which is working.  The problem is this code will be in a form and i can't have nested forms.  How do i change the code, so this works with a `div` parent element instead of a `form`?

```
<form>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function inmet(form){
       form.in2met.value = ((form.inch.value -0) * 25.4).toFixed(2)
   }
</script>
<div id="calcbody">
    <div class="calctitle">Convert <br />Inches to Millimetres</div>
    <div class="singcalcquestion">Enter the Inches:
         <input class="box1" type="text" name="inch" />
    </div>
    <div class="singsubmit">
         <input onclick="inmet(this.form)" type="button" value="GO" />     
    </div>
    <div class="singcalcanswer">Equals in Millimetres:<br />
         <input class="calcbox2" type="text" readonly="readonly" name="in2met" />
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to use `Element.getElementsByClassName()` or a similar method to get the input field you want:

```
<div id="form-root">
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function inmet(calcRoot){
    calcRoot.getElementsByClassName('calcbox2')[0].value = ((form.inch.value -0) * 25.4).toFixed(2);
  }
  // example: inmet(document.getElementById('form-root'))
  </script>
  <div id="calcbody">
    <div class="calctitle">Convert <br />Inches to Millimetres</div>
    <div class="singcalcquestion">Enter the Inches: <input class="box1" type="text" name="inch" /></div>
    <div class="singsubmit"><input onclick="inmet(document.getElementById('form-root'))" type="button" value="GO" /></div>
    <div class="singcalcanswer">Equals in Millimetres:<br /><input class="calcbox2" type="text" readonly="readonly" name="in2met" /></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the cleanest solution, but it should do the job:

```html
<div>
    <script>
        function inmet() {
            document.getElementById('in2met').value = ((document.getElementById('inch').value - 0) * 25.4).toFixed(2)
        }
    </script>
    <div id="calcbody">
        <div class="calctitle">Convert <br/>Inches to Millimetres</div>
        <div class="singcalcquestion">
            <label for="inch">Enter the Inches:</label>
            <input class="box1" type="text" name="inch" id="inch"/>
        </div>
        <div class="singsubmit">
            <input onclick="inmet()" type="button" value="GO"/>
        </div>
        <div class="singcalcanswer">
            <label for="in2met">Equals in Millimetres:</label>
            <input class="calcbox2" type="text" readonly="readonly" name="in2met" id="in2met"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```